# how to convert language in Excel Sheet?

Tags: excel

I have excel sheet in Spanish Language. I want to convert it in English and visa versa.

Can anybody please suggest me way to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

I would probably insert a cell in which it says "English" or "Spanish".

Put all the spanish words on a separate Sheet, called Spanish, and all English words on one called English. Let the words be in the corresponding cells in each sheet. Then use an IF statement. So you can select.

If in the sheet itself, you put then a link to the Cell with the word inside and just change the sheet name depending on what is selected in your language cell.